# Node.js Mocha testing- reporting to database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

We are using Mocha for testing Node.js applications. By default, the output goes to stdout - my question is - how can we direct the output to a database so that the results can be seen through a web UI? Is there a reporter from Mocha that handles writing to a DB? Or is async reporting not really an available feature for Mocha?